# How to sign data(string) in wp8

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

App will receive a token (string) from server. I want to sign this token with private key. I will pass on corresponding public key and signed token back to server in next request. Now server will validate that token using public key to check whether request is coming from authenticated user.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you tried to do it?

Comment: I tried it as 
 UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
 CspParameters parameters = new CspParameters();
 parameters.KeyContainerName = "MyContainer";
 RSACryptoServiceProvider obj = new  RSACryptoServiceProvider(parameters);
                
 byte[] dataToEncrypt=ByteConverter.GetBytes(inputDataInString);
 byte[] a=obj.SignData(dataToEncrypt, "SHA256");
 bool value = obj.VerifyData(dataToEncrypt, "SHA256", a);
 string SentToServer= Convert.ToBase64String(a);

 Can server verify that this SentToServer string  is signed by "SHA256"?